# Diferencia de tiempo de una transacción con otra - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

actualmente tengo un query que muestra todas las transacciones que un cliente ha realizado con una tarjeta de crédito, todo bien, pero quiero agregar un campo en el cual me diga cuanto tiempo hay entre una transacción y otra, por ejemplo si realizo una transacción con dicha tarjeta a las 4 PM y otra a las 6 PM, no se si habrá alguna manera de mostrar que entre esas 2 transacciones pasaron 2 horas, o si es entre dias y asi, este es el query

```
SELECT 
tr.tn_referencia AS NumeroTransaccion,
tr.tn_fchtrx AS Fecha,
tr.description AS Descripcion,
UPPER(cl.FullnameLocal) AS PropietarioTarjeta,
tr.tn_total AS Monto


FROM dbo.transacciones              AS tr
INNER JOIN  dbo.tc_tarjetas         AS tar    ON tar.ta_tarjeta=tr.tn_tarjeta
INNER JOIN  dbo.cl_clientesT        AS cli    ON cli.cl_cliente =tar.ta_cliente
INNER JOIN  dbo.Clients             AS cl     ON cl.ClientId=cli.cl_mis
```

El cual me arroja lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Este es un ejemplo de como muestra el resultado de un solo cliente)

Pero como puedo hacer para agregar el campo que me diga cuanto tiempo ha pasado entre una transacción y otra, estuve leyendo que con DATEIFF pero no se como plantearlo o si debo usar tablas temporales

Si alguien me ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución más simple, es utilizar la función de ventana Lag, que permite obtener el resultado de la fila anterior en la row en la que estamos.

```
Create Table #table
                     (
                     Transaccion        varchar(15)
                   , Fecha              datetime
                   , Proceso            varchar(100)
                   , PropietarioTarjeta varchar(100)
                   , Monto              money
                     );
```

Ahora los datos expuestos:

```
Insert into #table (
          Transaccion
        , Fecha             
        , Proceso           
        , PropietarioTarjeta
        , Monto   
        )
Values
('743..030','20210102 06:46:10.337','COMPRA','Jose Alberto',217.71),
('000..889','20210107 15:51:57.920','PAGO T','Jose Alberto',10000),
('000..848','20210107 15:51:28.120','PAGO T','Jose Alberto',49000),
('000..136','20210109 20:44:23.470','PAGO T','Jose Alberto',49000);
```

Un primer acercamiento, para comprobar su funcionamiento y ver como luego podemos aplicar el dateDiff

```
SELECT D.*, 
    LAG(Fecha,1)OVER(PARTITION BY PropietarioTarjeta
    ORDER BY Fecha DESC, Transaccion) AS ANT
    FROM
    (
    -- ORIGEN DE LOS DATOS
    SELECT * FROM #table T
    ) AS D
```

[image: Result]

**Lag** nos devuelve el resultado de la fila anterior, para cada `PropietarioTarjeta`, ordenado por la fecha descendiente, y por la transacción. Dos cosas importantes. El propietario tarjeta, no debería de ser el fullname, sino la clave primaria de cl, pero como no está en la consulta, he puesto el fullname, ya que si dos clientes, se llamasen igual....la liariamos.

Además el order by debe de ser determinista, de ahí que además de la fecha, este puesto la transación, porque si el mismo cliente, tuviera dos operaciones con la misma fecha (cosa que parece difícil a priori), nos asegura que dos operaciones devuelvan siempre lo mismo.

Como puedes ver en la imagen, la columna `Ant`, satisface el requerimiento.

Ahora ya usamos DateDiff, para obtener la diferencia, en unidades de tiempo entre dos fechas.

```
SELECT D.*, 
    DATEDIFF(SECOND,Fecha,LAG(Fecha,1)OVER(PARTITION BY PropietarioTarjeta
    ORDER BY Fecha DESC, Transaccion)) AS UT
    FROM
    (
    -- ORIGEN DE LOS DATOS
    SELECT * FROM #table T
    ) AS D
```

[image: Result]

Aquí ya hemos añadido la función datediff, que tiene los tres parámetros que requiere:

- Second: En que unidad de tiempo quieres la diferencia. Aquí es donde tienes que decidir lo que necesitas. [DateDiff](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- Fecha: Columna con el valor.
- Lag...: La Fecha de la fila anterior, que habíamos visto en la query anterior.

Por tanto, si quieres horas, solo tienes que adaptar el ***primer parámetro***
*second*, por *hour*. Si quieres días, por *day*.

[Lag/Lead](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lag-y-lead-siguiente-y-anterior/)

Comment: Funciono a la perfección, Muchas gracias